# Error: ltsp-build-client --arch i386

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-16.04, ltsp

I'm attempting to configure LTSP for the first time on my linux machine and seem to keep running into this issue when executing the command

'ltsp-build-client --arch i386'

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/freerdp/libfreerdp-client1.1_1.1.0~git20140921.1.44091e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1_i386.deb Hash Sum mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/univers/s/sshfs-fuse/sshfs_2.5-1ubuntu1_i386.deb Hash Sum mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
error: LTSP client installation ended abnormally
```

In an attempt to solve this, I have run apt-get update multiple times and tried with the --fix-missing postfix. I am also running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Any help is appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Try remove all the contents of /var/lib/apt/lists/ directory:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

then run:

```
apt-get update
```

then:

```
ltsp-build-client --arch i386
```